# Como substituir o valor de uma propriedade em um objeto utilizando spread?

Tags: javascript

Eu estou com uma dúvida em um exercício desde ontem e não consigo achar nada na net. O problema é o seguinte: eu preciso alterar o valor da propriedade CIDADE e colocar outro nome nela, porém quando eu tento alterar, ele reescreve o campo de endereço deixando apenas o valor que tentei alterar.

Código abaixo para contextualizar:

```js
const usuario = { nome: "Rafael", idade: 17, 
   endereco: { cidade: "Guatapará", uf: "SP", pais: "Brasil" }
};

const usuario2 = { ...usuario, endereco: { cidade: "Ribeirão Preto" } };
```

O que eu espero obter é o seguinte:

```js
{ nome: 'Rafael', idade: 19, endereco: { cidade: "Ribeirão Preto", uf: "SP", pais: "Brasil" }}
```

Mas o que recebo é:

```js
{ nome: 'Rafael', idade: 19, endereco: { cidade: 'Ribeirão' }}
```

Como podem ver, dentro da propriedade de endereço só ficou a cidade. Como posso corrigir isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### O que está acontecendo:

Quando você utiliza o spread no objeto, você recebe um novo objeto com as mesmas propriedades e valores, `{...usuario}` retornaria o mesmo valor.

Ao usar o uma segunda propriedade, você está adicionando ou substituindo. `endereco: { cidade: "Ribeirão Preto" }` substitui a propriedade `endereco` com o objeto `{ cidade: "Ribeirão Preto" }`, e é isso que você recebe.

#### Alternativa:

Se o seu exercício exige que você resolva através de spread, uma solução é fazer com que o endereço também seja uma "cópia" do endereço original:

```js
const usuario2 = { ...usuario, endereco: { ...usuario.endereco, cidade: "Ribeirão Preto" } }
```